# How to skip regex Catastrophic Backtracking

Tags: ruby, regex

I guess my input string is too long or/and has new lines.

What should I fix in the regex?

```
/^.+ (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) #{target} (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) .+$/
```

Edit:

In an input of example (bigger):

> n software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the **start** of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory. When a program

I would like assuming target is **start**  to extract the 3 words before and 3 words after

So extracted words: "determined at the" (left) and "of the program" (right)

Edit2:

After @Denys Séguret comment Catastrophic Backtracking is avoided. Regex is built this way in ruby:

```
regex =""
regex += "(\\S+) " * numLeft
regex += " #{target}"
regex += " (\\S+)" * numRight

pattern = Regexp.new(regex, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
matches = pattern.match(input)
```

Comment: It kinda depends on what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you have an exemple of Input/Output expected ?

Comment: Sorry I edited my question

Comment: Why not just `/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) #{target} (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)/` ? And if you can't have a # in the three words before and after, change the `(\S+)` to `[^\s#]+`, that should be enough.

Comment: Also, I did achieve to get a timeout but not catastrophic backtracking...

Comment: A space is probably missing  in the second line of your new code

Comment: The root cause is the first `.+`, solution is to remove `^.+` and `.+$`

Answer (score -1):

```
▶ target = 'start'
▶ input[/(\w+\s+){3}#{target}(\s+\w+){3}/]
#⇒ "determined at the start of the program"
```